Reference request: finding entries that prevent matrix from being correlation matrix
I am currently doing some research with a quantitative finance firm and my supervisor has raised an interesting question that shows up a lot with their clients: quite often, clients will want to do some forecast analysis for a collection of portfolios. A common input for this sort of analysis is a correlation matrix (by which I mean a symmetric positive semi-definite matrix with 1s along the diagonal), but the client only has partial information about the correlation between different portfolios, so they try to guess to fill in the rest and often end up with something that is not a correlation matrix (fails to be PSD).
The firm's current approach to this problem is to project the input matrix onto the space of correlation matrices to find the "nearest correlation matrix" (in the $L^2$ norm). This works well for the most part, but the problem is that clients have complained about the lack of transparency as to where the final correlation matrix comes from. My supervisor therefore wants to come up with a way to take the client's input matrix and highlight the parts that prevent it from being PSD (this is where the discussion becomes a bit hand-wavey, as we don't yet have a good definition for what this means and that will be part of my final question).
Example 1: As a simple example of what I mean, suppose we have three portfolios $A, B, C$. We know that $A$ and $B$ are both separately strongly positively correlated with $C$, but we don't know the relationship between $A$ and $B$. We (stupidly) guess that $A$ and $B$ are uncorrelated, resulting in the matrix
$$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0.9 \\ 0 & 1 & 0.9 \\ 0.9 & 0.9 & 1 \end{pmatrix}.$$
This matrix is not PSD (its smallest eigenvalue is $\sim -0.27 < 0$). It's easy to see here that the problem is caused by saying that $A$ and $B$ are uncorrelated, as that is incompatible with the constraint that $A, B$ are both strongly correlated with $C$. We would therefore want to identify the $(1, 2), (2,1)$ entries for the client.
To make this rigorous, we try to use the modified Sylvester's criterion for PSD matrices: a matrix is PSD if and only if all principal minors are non-negative. In this case, the minor that causes problems is the upper right (equiv. lower left) one, since
$$ \left| \begin{matrix} 0 & 0.9 \\ 1 & 0.9 \end{matrix} \right| = \left| \begin{matrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0.9 & 0.9 \end{matrix} \right| < 0. $$
Just from looking at that minor without the context of the rest of the matrix, it is not clear which entry is actually causing the problem, so we probably need to somehow cross-reference with other minors as well to deduce that the 0 is the problem. Part of my question is how to identify the 0 in this case as the obstacle to the full matrix being PSD.
My first naive approach was as follows: let's try fixing all but one entry (technically pair of entries, since the matrix is symmetric) at a time. By iterating over all off-diagonal entries and computing the minors, we could identify which entry is causing the minors to be negative and highlight this.
Example 2: That won't work because of the following: suppose we have two (disjoint and uncorrelated) collections $P, Q$ of portfolios, each of which the client has failed to give a correlation matrix for. We can consider the collection $P \coprod Q$ of all the portfolios together, which has the block "correlation" matrix
$$ P \oplus Q = \begin{pmatrix} P & 0 \\ 0 & Q \end{pmatrix}.$$
I'm slightly abusing notation here by denoting both the collections and their correlation matrices by the same thing, but hopefully you get what I mean. Since neither $P$ nor $Q$ is a correlation matrix, we need to fix at least two entries in $P \oplus Q$ so we can't just work one pair at a time.
Question: Has this problem been studied before? If so, could someone please provide some references to get me started? If not, does anyone have suggestions for a more rigorous definition of the "problematic entries"?

Maybe you want to find the closest correlation matrix by Hamming distance—the number of different values

Something is going wrong with how you're applying Sylvester's criterion. That criterion talks only about the principal minors. But the minors you're using to "prove" non-PSD-ness are not principal.
Anyway, it's not clear to me which of the following two things you want -- could you clarify? (a) If the given entries are compatible with a correlation matrix, your clients want to know how you found that correlation matrix. Or... (b) If the given entries are not compatible with a correlation matrix, your clients want to know why not.
Either way, look into semidefinite programming.

Right. The problem with the $3\times3$ is that the determinant – which is a principal minor – is negative.

If you want to change just one pair of entries, you could change a pair of $.9$ entires to $.4$, or change the zero entries to $.81$.
